# Four-finger Multitasking gesture activates UIPinchGestureRecognizer gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, multitasking-gestures

I am using a UIPinchGestureRecognizer, which uses 2 fingers by default. If a user decides to perform the multitask gesture, the pinch gestures action is also activated.

Is there a way to cancel the pinch gesture from occurring if more than four UITouch instances are detected?

**Edit Removed sample code as it was the wrong approach.**

Comment: Are you subclassing `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Not subclassing it, just instantiating it.

Answer (score 1):

With a multitask gesture, the `numberOfTouches` returned by the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` is 2 instead of 4 or 5, because some touches are ignored.

You can subclass `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and override `ignoreTouch:forEvent` to cancel the recognizer if the event has 4 or 5 touches:

```
- (void) ignoreTouch:(UITouch*)touch forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [super ignoreTouch:touch forEvent:event];

    // Cancel recognizer during a multitask gesture
    if ([[event allTouches] count] > 3)
    {
        self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not subclassing the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, you shouldn't be using `touchBegan:withEvent:`. Instead you should be handling it in the method that is called when a pinch occurs.

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
    // if there are 2 fingers being used
    if ([pinchGestureRecognizer numberOfTouches] == 2) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing that a little while after posting this question. The problem is that iOS sometimes detects only 2 or 3 fingers immediately when you try doing the four-finger swipe, and the pinch goes off instead of the taskbar appearing.